# How come this bash script can write 'a'?

Tags: bash

```
#/bin/bash

PATH_GSUTIL=""
[ -f "$PATH_GSUTIL"/gsutil ] || (echo "$PATH_GSUTIL does not contain 'gsutil'" && exit)
echo a
```

I would expect it to quit on `exit`. How come it goes on and executes the next line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`()` command grouping operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) creates a sub-shell, which is what you're exiting from.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon [unwind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9359895/947357): `()` creates a subshell which then executes the `exit`. You can use the `{}` (with some more whitespace required around the `{` and `}`). That will do the job in your case, because the `exit` will then be executed by the outer shell.